# CardEmulation.registerAidsForService not working

Tags: android, hce

I am working on an Android HCE application and I would like to dynamically add AIDs at runtime for a given service. Fortunatelly for me Android API 21 has added the method `CardEmulation.registerAidsForService()` specifically for that.
Unfortunatelly I cannot make it work no matter what.
I have tried to register both a `HostApduService` and a normal `Service`, but the method always returns false.

I can't figure out what the correct approach is as the documentation is quite scarce and I couldn't find any working example.

Registering a service statically for an AID group worked for me so I figured that it shouldn't be a HCE problem, a permission problem or a problem with the device itself (a Note 4 N910C).

I don't know what other approach I should take.
Any information would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it myself.

It seems bo be working with an `HostApduService` but I omitted to add the following line to the manifest file:

```
<meta-data android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.host_apdu_service" android:resource="@xml/apduservice"/>
```

In my stupidity, I thought it might be useless for dynamic usage. For those interested `xml/apduservice.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<host-apdu-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description="@string/servicedesc"
    android:requireDeviceUnlock="false">
</host-apdu-service>
```

Unsurprisingly, the code is similar to the one in the sample [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html).

Comment: This was exactly my problem as well.